# String not convertible to [AnyObject]

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

I have a string declared as `var searchString =  ""`

I am trying to do parse query as shown below: `query?.whereKey("username", containedIn: searchString)`

What is the issue?

This is in Xcode 6.3 updated and also Swift 1.2.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function expects an array of AnyObjects, you supply a String. Simply wrap the string in an array...

```
query?.whereKey("username", containedIn: [searchString])
```

Comment: Oh thanks, you are right. Your second answer is right: `query?.whereKey("username", containedIn: [searchString])`

Comment: Any chance you may know the answer to this too?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29874414/cannot-subscript-a-value-of-anyobject-with-an-index-of-type-int