# Cannot subscript a value of [AnyObject]? with an index of type Int

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform, xcode6.3

This is in a class extending [PFQueryTableViewController](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQueryTableViewController.html) and I am getting the following error. The rows will be `PFUser` only.
Why am I not able to cast it? Is there a way around this?

The error is:

```
Cannot subscript a value of [AnyObject]? with an index of type Int
```

...for this line:

```
var user2 = self.objects[indexPath.row] as! PFUser
```

[image]

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The problem isn't the cast, but the fact that `self.objects` seems to be an optional array: `[AnyObject]?`. Therefore, if you want to access one of its values via a subscript, you have to unwrap the array first:

```
var user2: PFUser
if let userObject = self.objects?[indexPath.row] {
    user2 = userObject as! PFUser
} else {
    // Handle the case of `self.objects` being `nil`.
}
```

The expression `self.objects?[indexPath.row]` uses [optional chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html) to first unwrap `self.objects`, and then call its subscript.

---

As of Swift 2, you could also use the [guard statement](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID120):

```
var user2: PFUser
guard let userObject = self.objects?[indexPath.row] else {
    // Handle the case of `self.objects` being `nil` and exit the current scope.
}
user2 = userObject as! PFUser
```

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same issue and resolved it like this:

```
let scope : String = searchBar.scopeButtonTitles![searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex] as! String
```

For your case, you might do:

```
var user2 : PFUser = self.objects![indexPath.row] as! PFUser
```

Answer (score 3):

My workaround would be..

1. If you are certain that the tableview will contain only users try to typecast the objects Array of AnyObject to Array of PFUser. then use it.

Comment: that still gives error, but this works, not sure why: `var user2 = self.objects![indexPath.row] as! PFUser`

Comment: Because objects Array is optional [AnyObject]?

Answer (score 1):

Just add an ! (exclamation mark) after objects, like so:

```
var user2 = self.objects![indexPath.row] as! PFUser
```

That fixed it for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with the following line:

```
array![row]
```

I could not understand where the issue came from; if I replaced `row` with a number like `1` the code compiled and ran without any issues.

Then I had the happy thought of changing it to this:

```
array![Int(row)]
```

And it worked. For the life of me, I don't understand why giving an array an index of `-1`is theoretically legal, but there you go. It makes sense to me for subscripts to be unsigned, but maybe it's just me; I'll have to ask [Chris](http://www.nondot.org/sabre/) about it.