# Converting values in swift 2

Tags: ios, swift

I am migrating from swift 1.2 to 2.0 following code was working well in swift 1.2 but in 2.0 doesn't

```
    let data = dataContainer["d"] as NSArray!
    for item in data {
        var username: String = item["username"] as! String
    }
```

I am getting this compiler error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'String' to specified type 'String'
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you using the latest, released Xcode? The Swift team hopes they have eliminated all of the "Cannot convert 'x' to 'x'" errors. If you're getting one, you should open a radar. https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: 7.0 final release, not beta, right? If so, please do open a radar. You should never see this kind of error message. It's masking your actual syntax error.

Comment: Also, you should indicate exactly where you get the error, and your actual Swift 2.0 code (the `as NSArray!` doesn't look like correct Swift 2).

Comment: Just to be sure, you downloaded your Xcode from the Mac App Store right? :)

Comment: @appzYourLife hahahha yes i am sure :)

Comment: @RobNapier My code looks like this: http://prntscr.com/8jqpux

Comment: @Okan: ok, I asked because of this: http://www.macrumors.com/2015/09/20/xcodeghost-chinese-malware-faq/

Comment: @appzYourLife Yeah, I know it

Comment: @Okan: how is `dataContainer` defined?

Comment: @appzYourLife http://prntscr.com/8jqr8u

Comment: I can't reproduce this in Xcode 7 using your posted code. Can you produce a MCVE? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I guess, i should never move to swift 2. Becase I am getting tons of errors and I can't handle it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the type of data container

Comment: What happens if you just say `var username = item["username"] as! String` ?

Comment: @Paulw11 http://prntscr.com/8k8gi9

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29874414/cannot-subscript-a-value-of-anyobject-with-an-index-of-type-int - what is `results`? That is a different variable to what you had before

Comment: Also, you generally don't need to type variables with Swift if it can work it out from context - can you try `let dataContainer = notification.userInfo  as! Dictionary<String,NSArray!>
    let data = dataContainer["d"] as NSArray!
    for item in data  {
        let username = item["username"] as! String
        print(username)
    }
`

Comment: or even `func processComments(notification:NSNotification) {
    
    let dataContainer = notification.userInfo  as! Dictionary<String,NSArray>
    if let data = dataContainer["d"]  {
        for item in data  {
            let username = item["username"] as! String
            print(username)
        }
    }
}` - it depends are you putting optional arrays into the NSNotification dictionary?

Comment: I tried your second code: http://prntscr.com/8kbal7