# Error when I want to access a row via the indexPath in a tableViewController

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift2, xcode7, nsindexpath

I am making a chat app. I am having a problem while accessing an array of objects via indexPath(row) of a tableViewController. It is giving me an error: " Cannot subscript a value of type '[AnyObject]?'" The code is below. How do I fix this?

```
var user1 = PFUser.currentUser()
var user2 = self.objects[indexPath.row] as! PFUser
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot subscript a value of AnyObject? with an index of type Int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29874414/cannot-subscript-a-value-of-anyobject-with-an-index-of-type-int)

Comment: try unwrapping objects as follows: var user1 = PFUser.currentUser()
var user2 = self.objects![indexPath.row] as! PFUser

Answer (score 0):

You may change the declaration of your `self.objects` to:

```
var objects = Array<PFUser>()
```

and use it like:

```
let user = self.objects[indexPath.row] as BusinessLocation!
```

Since you have specified the type, it won't consider it as `AnyObject`.