# Swift Dictionary Representation

Tags: swift, dictionary, foundation

I'm working on creating a Swift `Dictionary` out of some custom objects.

Below is where I define the dictionary;
`var carDictionary:[String:Any] = Dictionary<String, Any>()`

The for loop below is where I'm trying to populate the dictionary out of my custom objects:

```
 for dataPoint in dataPoints! {
     carDictionary[dataPoint.value(forKey: dataPoint.dataKey)]
 }
```

`dataPoint` is an instance of the following class:

```
public class NACarDataPoint: NSObject {

    var dataKey: String!
    var dataValue: Any!

    public override init() {
        // generic initializer, generally designed to be overridden
        super.init()
    }

    init(key: String, value: Any) {
        self.dataKey = key
        self.dataValue = value
    }
}
```

I'm getting what appears to be the admittedly somewhat common error of

```
`Cannot subscript a value of type `[String : Any]` with an index of type `Any`?`
```

However, I think there's some missing part of my understanding of how dictionary creation works in Swift that's keeping me from figuring out the issue - anyone have any suggestions? Thank you!

Posts with similar problems:
[String not convertible to [AnyObject]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29874174/string-not-convertible-to-anyobject?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : String]?' with an index of type 'String'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30020362/cannot-subscript-a-value-of-type-string-string-with-an-index-of-type-str)

[Cannot subscript a value of [AnyObject]? with an index of type Int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29874414/cannot-subscript-a-value-of-anyobject-with-an-index-of-type-int#29874635)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're putting the value where it's expecting a key subscript.

Similar to arrays, you access objects in your dictionary like this:

```
let myValue = myDictionary["myKey"]
```

This retrieves the object in the dictionary that had the key "myKey". To instead set a value in the dictionary, assign to the key subscript like this:

```
myDictionary["myKey"] = myValue
```

In your case, it looks like your dataPoint class has key and value objects that can be used in the dictionary:

```
 for dataPoint in dataPoints! {
     carDictionary[dataKey] = dataPoint.value(forKey: dataPoint.dataKey)
 }
```